# How to do a bar plot in a for loop for each variable?

Tags: r, for-loop

I do not know why this code isn't working I tried everything. I am trying to do a barplot for each variable in mycatvar (which is 2 variables) vs the group (which is treatment or control).

```
NumVars =    
nnumvar  = Data[c(2,4,5,6,7,8)]   
MyTotTitles = c("titles..")  
CatVars =   
mycatvar = Data[c(1,3)]   
MyCatTitles = c("??? by Treatment Group", "??? by Treatment Group")for (i in 1:ncol(mycatvar)){
  y=mycatvar[,i] 
  mytitle= paste(mycatvar[i],"By Treatment Group")
  myxlab= mycatvar[i]
  myylab= "Group"
  n.var=ncol(Data)
  GNames = c("Control", "Treatment") 
    
  GFREQS=table(mycatvar[,i],Data[,9])
  GFREQS 

  XTFREQS=table(Data[,9],mycatvar[,i])
  XTFREQS
  barplot(GFREQS,horiz=TRUE,
      col=c("red","blue"),
      names.arg= GNames, cex.names=2,
      main=mytitle,
      xlab=myxlab,
      ylab=myylab)
}
```

This is what comes out:
[image: example.png]

Comment: It would be good to have a small representative data set to understand how your data is structured.

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70148978/edit) with the data and then delete this long comment. Also, that data is not reproducible. What is `Data`? Please post the output of `dput(mydata)`.

Comment: Did it. `Data` is way to long to post the output.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more of your data, likely the issue is your title and x label variables where `mycatvar[i]` returns a data frame of one column by `nrows` –not a *single* value. Therefore, the output dumps all column values in bold title at top and all column values for x label at bottom.

Specifically, see comments on current lines:

```r
for (i in 1:ncol(mycatvar)){
  y=mycatvar[,i]                                    # ASSIGNED, NEVER USED
  mytitle= paste(mycatvar[i],"By Treatment Group")  # PASTE ENTIRE COLUMN OF VALUES
  myxlab= mycatvar[i]                               # LABEL ENTIRE COLUMN OF VALUES
  myylab= "Group"
  n.var=ncol(Data)                                  # ASSIGNED, NEVER USED
  ...
}
```

Likely, you meant to return the name of corresponding column for a single value.

```r
for (i in 1:ncol(mycatvar)){
  mytitle <- paste( 
      colnames(mycatvar)[i],           # PASTE SINGLE VALUE
      "By Treatment Group"
  )
  myxlab <- colnames(mycatvar)[i]      # LABEL SINGLE VALUE
  myylab <- "Group" 
  ...

}
```

Alternatively, you can iterate through column names and pass those into extractor, `[[`, calls. Below removes assigned variables that are not used and uses the assignment operator, `<-`:

```r
for (col in colnames(mycatvar)){
  mytitle <- paste(col, "By Treatment Group")
  myxlab <- col
  myylab <- "Group"

  GNames <- c("Control", "Treatment")     
  GFREQS <- table(mycatvar[[col]], Data[,9])
  GFREQS 

  XTFREQS <- table(Data[,9], mycatvar[[col]])
  XTFREQS

  barplot(
     GFREQS,
     horiz = TRUE,
     col = c("red","blue"),
     names.arg = GNames, 
     cex.names = 2,
     main = mytitle,
     xlab = myxlab,
     ylab = myylab
  )
}
```